# Grouping with child node value and sum the values of grouped once

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a scenario like below, i want to group the elements with child element value and sum up the quantity. with xslt 1.0.

```
Input:
<body>
    <Root1>
        <Root2>
            <E1>abc</merchantcode>
            <C1>
                <order>
                    <catalog>
                        <catalogitem>100</catalogitem>
                        <sku>100</sku>
                        <quantity>1</quantity>
                    </catalog>
                </order>
            </C1>
            <C1>
                <order>
                    <catalog>
                        <catalogitem>100</catalogitem>
                        <sku>100</sku>
                        <quantity>2</quantity>
                    </catalog>
                </order>
            </C1>
            <C1>
                <order>
                    <catalog>
                        <catalogitem>111</catalogitem>
                        <sku>111</sku>
                        <quantity>1</quantity>
                    </catalog>
                </order>
            </C1>
        </Root2>
    </Root1>
</body>
```

i want to group the above XML document based on the sku value. then want to sum the quantity.
Here is my desired Result:

```
<body>
    <Root1>
        <Root2>
            <E1>abc</merchantcode>
            <C1>
                <order>
                    <catalog>
                        <catalogitem>100</catalogitem>
                        <sku>100</sku>
                        <quantity>3</quantity>
                    </catalog>
                </order>
            </C1>
            <C1>
                <order>
                    <catalog>
                        <catalogitem>111</catalogitem>
                        <sku>111</sku>
                        <quantity>1</quantity>
                    </catalog>
                </order>
            </C1>
        </Root2>
    </Root1>
</body>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: i Have tried like this, but it did not work <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::Root1)]"/>
   <xsl:for-each-group select="Root1" group-by="Root2/catalog/sku">
    <xsl:variable name="quantity">
     <xsl:value-of select="sum(/message/body/orderImport/orderHeader/Root1/Root2/catalog[sku = current-grouping-key()]/quantity)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
     <quantity>
      <xsl:value-of select="$quantity" />
     </quantity>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:for-each-group> 
  </xsl:copy>

Comment: The text says "with xslt 1.0", the tag says [tag:xslt-2.0]. Your code in the comment uses `xsl:for-each-group` which would XSLT 2 or 3. So which version do you use or can you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Root2">
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* except C1"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="C1" group-by="order/catalog/sku"> 
            <C1>
                <order>
                    <catalog>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="order/catalog/(catalogitem | sku)" /> 
                        <quantity>
                            <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/order/catalog/quantity)" /> 
                        </quantity>
                    </catalog>
                </order>
            </C1>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**XSLT 1.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kCatalogsByItemaAndSKU" match="C1"
   use="concat(order/catalog/catalogitem, '+', order/catalog//sku)"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="C1"/>

  <xsl:template match="C1[generate-id()
                         = generate-id(key('kCatalogsByItemaAndSKU',
                                            concat(order/catalog/catalogitem,
                                                  '+', order/catalog/sku)
                                            )[1]
                                       )
                          ]">
    <C1><xsl:apply-templates/></C1>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="C1/order/catalog/quantity/text()">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "sum(key('kCatalogsByItemaAndSKU',
               concat(../../catalogitem, '+', ../../sku)
               )/order/catalog/quantity)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (fixed to be made wellformed):

```
<body>
    <Root1>
        <Root2>
            <E1>abc</E1>
            <C1>
                <order>
                    <catalog>
                        <catalogitem>100</catalogitem>
                        <sku>100</sku>
                        <quantity>1</quantity>
                    </catalog>
                </order>
            </C1>
            <C1>
                <order>
                    <catalog>
                        <catalogitem>100</catalogitem>
                        <sku>100</sku>
                        <quantity>2</quantity>
                    </catalog>
                </order>
            </C1>
            <C1>
                <order>
                    <catalog>
                        <catalogitem>111</catalogitem>
                        <sku>111</sku>
                        <quantity>1</quantity>
                    </catalog>
                </order>
            </C1>
        </Root2>
    </Root1>
</body>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<body>
   <Root1>
      <Root2>
         <E1>abc</E1>
         <C1>
            <order>
               <catalog>
                  <catalogitem>100</catalogitem>
                  <sku>100</sku>
                  <quantity>3</quantity>
               </catalog>
            </order>
         </C1>
         <C1>
            <order>
               <catalog>
                  <catalogitem>111</catalogitem>
                  <sku>111</sku>
                  <quantity>1</quantity>
               </catalog>
            </order>
         </C1>
      </Root2>
   </Root1>
</body>
```